# Use Regex for XML

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'd like to find all instances of the following from within a larger chunk of XML code.

```
      <grouptool id="688" rect="20,576,456,141">
        <imagetool id="689" rect="349.15241201716736,581.50668036999,111.22746781115886,132.83658787255914">
          <toolstroke WIDTH="1.0" CAP="2" JOIN="2" MITER="0.0" />
          <bordercolor />
          <image name="head-set-md.png" type="CLIPART" size="20419" w="252" h="300" CRC="3224584205" />
        </imagetool>
        <rectangletool id="690" rect="20,576,455.0214592274678,141">
          <toolstroke />
          <toolcolor />
          <fillcolor RGB="16777215" ALPHA="0" />
        </rectangletool>
        <texttool id="691" rect="30,584,214,31">
          <toolstroke />
          <toolcolor />
          <font style="3" size="24" />
          <Text>Got Audio Problems?</Text>
        </texttool>
        <texttool id="692" rect="33,667,266,23">
          <toolstroke />
          <toolcolor />
          <font style="2" size="18" />
          <Text>Note: Audio problems can be caused</Text>
        </texttool>
        <imagetool id="693" rect="36.1785407725322,631.7913669064748,262.9012875536481,24.345323741007192">
          <toolstroke WIDTH="1.0" CAP="2" JOIN="2" MITER="0.0" />
          <bordercolor />
          <image name="unknown.png" type="CLIPART" size="1777" w="260" h="24" CRC="2321804736" />
        </imagetool>
        <texttool id="694" rect="32,688,269,23">
          <toolstroke />
          <toolcolor />
          <font style="2" size="18" />
          <Text>by a weak/spotty internet connection.</Text>
        </texttool>
        <rectangletool id="695" rect="249.53304721030045,627.7338129496403,30.33476394849785,31.44604316546762">
          <toolstroke WIDTH="4.0" />
          <toolcolor RGB="52224" />
          <fillcolor RGB="16777215" ALPHA="0" />
        </rectangletool>
      </grouptool>
```

The key is the `rect="20,576,456,141"` in the first line.  Ultimately, I'll be replacing the contents of the `<grouptool>` tag with something else, but I only need to do that for the `<grouptool>` that has the property `rect="20,576,456,141"`.

I'll be using VSCode code for this and have tried a couple things so far that have failed.

Fail #1: `<grouptool\b[^>]*?\brect="20,576,456,141"(?:(?!<grouptool\b).)*</grouptool>`

Fail #2: `<\bgrouptool.*\brect\=\"20\,576\,456\,141\"([\s\S]*?)<\/\bgrouptool>`

I hardly know anything about Regex.  Please advise if you're able.

Comment: Well, regex is the wrong tool for the job but if you insist then try `<grouptool [^>]*?rect="20,576,456,141"[^>]*?>[\s\S]+?<\/grouptool>`. https://regex101.com/r/DwW3LW/1

Comment: ^ Though you might want to add `(?<= )` before `rect` to enforce a space. Otherwise `<grouptool not-rect="...">` also hits.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Not married to Regex.  I just want to get the job done.  There are hundreds of files that this need to happen on though, so doing this through something like VSCode seemed to be the best way.  Did you have a better solution in mind?

Comment: Yes, learn XSLT formatting and apply it to your files. Regex is far too prone to edge-case issues. You'll have to verify that each replacement was done properly. I hope you're saving an original copy of those files before attempting such a massive replacement.

Comment: With regex, you could probably achieve what you want with `(<grouptool(?:\s[^>]*)?\srect="20,576,456,141"[^>]*>)[\w\W]*?(</grouptool>)` and replacing with `$1New Value$2`

Comment: Assuming the surrounding XML is present in its own file, and not part of a script. Another option would be to write a small script using an XML builder. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/8f96d129c504899e0686e6c2b09e3876) using the Ruby [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) gem, but other languages probably offer their own solutions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This seems to be working!  I'm happy to mark this as the accepted answer if you post it as a formal answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, you can search for

```js
(<grouptool(?:\s[^>]*)?\srect="20,576,456,141"[^>]*>)[\w\W]*?(</grouptool>)
```

and replace with `$1New Value$2`.

*Details*:

- `(` - Group 1 (`$1`):

  - `<grouptool` - a fixed string
  - `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace and then zero or more chars other than `>`
  - `\srect="20,576,456,141"` - a whitespace and a `rect="20,576,456,141"` string
  - `[^>]*>` - zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `[\w\W]*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(</grouptool>)` - Group 2 (`$2`): a `</grouptool>` string.